# AWS gzip: stdout: No space left on device

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Why every time I try to compress all Apache "www" dir on my instance - running with ubuntu - I got this message "gzip: stdout: No space left on device" I use this cmd "tar -zcvf backup.tar.gs /var/www/*"

Comment: use df -k and then remove files in tmp files

Answer (score 2):

You are out of storage. Nothing special to Amazon services, really. Delete stuff, or buy more storage. `df -h` will show you currently mounted filesystems and their used space. `du` will help you tally filesystem usage by directory.

Answer (score 1):

The partition/mountpoint on which you write is too full. You should delete some stuff or use a different partition for writing your archive.

If just a few bytes are needed on the server then *maybe*

```
tar cf - /var/www/*|gzip -9 >backup.tar.gz
```

will work even if "tar czf" fails.

If you are not root and you can only login with ssh as normal user then you may use sshfs or something like

```
ssh myself@server "tar cf - /var/www/*|gzip -9" >backup.tar.gz
```

to store it on the fly to your local disk.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably run out of disk-space.

If you have ssh access, I would first run a :

```
df -h
```

that give you which volumes you have and the size and free space on each volume.

```
df -h .
```

with the **dot** added, you should get the same but based on your current folder.